# How do I insert an empty line/space inside tabular environment (with empty columns)?

Tags: spacing, tabularx

I have a tabular environment, where I want to separate "paragraphs" with empty lines or spaces. The paragraphs have one major title on the left whereas the column on the right has several lines. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}l<{}@{\ }X@{}}
    \textbf{Paragraph 1} &
    \textbf{Header 1} \\
    & Next line \\
    & Third piece of text \\
    & Fourth line of text \\

    % \medskip

    \textbf{Paragraph 2} &
    \textbf{Header 2} \\
    & Next line \\
    & Third piece of text \\
    & Fourth line of text 
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In the middle I have commented out `\medskip` command that would insert the space I need. However, that appears unintuitively after the second paragaph header not before it:

[image]

I found similar problem here: https://www.reddit.com/r/LaTeX/comments/5om827/vspace_after_newline_in_tabularx/

The solution is to use `\vskip` command, but somehow that brings an error message in the table form that I need:

```
ERROR: Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr
```

My guess is that I should tweak the line `\begin{tabularx}` but I have no idea how.

Comment: Is there a special reason for using a table for this kind of content? If the text in the paragraphs gets longer you might get problems with page breaks (unless you use a longtable). Maybe you could use a `description` environment instead?

Comment: Good point! `tabular` works in my case because the "table" won't stretch several pages. For more general cases, I need to familiarize myself with `description`. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}l<{}@{\ }X@{}}
    \textbf{Paragraph 1} &
    \textbf{Header 1} \\
    & Next line \\
    & Third piece of text \\
    & Fourth line of text \\[2cm]

    \textbf{Paragraph 2} &
    \textbf{Header 2} \\
    & Next line \\
    & Third piece of text \\
    & Fourth line of text 
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

or perhaps better

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}l<{}@{\ }X@{}}
    \textbf{Paragraph 1} &
    \textbf{Header 1} \\
    & Next line \\
    & Third piece of text \\
    & Fourth line of text 

\vspace{2\baselineskip}\\

    \textbf{Paragraph 2} &
    \textbf{Header 2} \\
    & Next line \\
    & Third piece of text \\
    & Fourth line of text 
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```